# Write to excel but keep original headers which match the columns of reference dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

reference:

```
Primary Site   Specification ID   Brand Name
Site1          1234               Brand1
Site2          12345              Brand2
Site3          123456             Brand3
```

also : I have 2 blank files kept in a folder which looks like:
file1

```
SPEC_ID           Z_PRIMARY_SITE 
Specification ID  Primary Site
```

file2:

```
BRAND_VALUE_NAME
Brand Name
```

My motive is to write the data from reference df to the files wherever the row=1 from the file matches with the header of the reference df.

I am using the below code:

```
path = "path where files are kept"
file_list = os.listdir(path)
for i in file_list:
    filename = os.path.join(path, i)
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, header = 1) #to match the 1st row of file to the header of reference df
    cond = df.columns.intersection(reference.columns)
    reference[cond].to_excel(filename,index = False)
```

I am achieving the result and the data is getting split and written in the matching columns too, however I would want to keep the original header of the file for eg:Z_PRIMARY_SITE, etc. intact while writing the data into excel.

Present output: for file 1 and so on:

```
Specification ID  Primary Site
1234               Site1
12345              Site2
123456             Site3
```

Expected output for file1 and so on:

```
SPEC_ID           Z_PRIMARY_SITE 
Specification ID  Primary Site
1234               Site1
12345              Site2
123456             Site3
```

Is there a way to achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
#added new column for testing
print (df)
            SPEC_ID Z_PRIMARY_SITE new
0  Specification ID   Primary Site  tt

#intersection by first row
cond = pd.Index(df.iloc[0]).intersection(reference.columns)
df1 = reference[cond].copy()
#create first row by columns names
df1.loc[-1] = df1.columns
d = dict(zip(df.iloc[0], df.columns))
#and rename columns for df columns
df1 = df1.sort_index().rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
             SPEC_ID Z_PRIMARY_SITE
-1  Specification ID   Primary Site
 0              1234          Site1
 1             12345          Site2
 2            123456          Site3
```

Alternative solution:

```
cond = pd.Index(df.iloc[0]).intersection(reference.columns)
df1 = reference[cond].copy()
df1 = pd.DataFrame([df1.columns], columns=df1.columns).append(df1)
d = dict(zip(df.iloc[0], df.columns))
df1 = df1.rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
            SPEC_ID Z_PRIMARY_SITE
0  Specification ID   Primary Site
0              1234          Site1
1             12345          Site2
2            123456          Site3
```

---

```
df1.to_excel(filename,index = False)
```

Comment: but df and reference df both has same headers since I am reading the df as header = 1 just so that I can perform the intersection. So it wouldnot append the original headers. what do you think? :)

Comment: @anky_91 - Yes, you are right. so solution should be swap values and columns names first by `df = pd.DataFrame(data=df.columns, columns=df.iloc[0])`

Comment: I will give it a try. :) Thanks. I have edited the question to put my present v/s expected output now. :)

Comment: just edited the output desired, sorry about that. :) Thank you. But I am getting the error Shape of passed values is (1, 7), indices imply (7, 7)

Comment: Unfortunately : ValueError: all arrays must be same length for the updated one. :(

Comment: @anky_91 - Can you check now?

Comment: error at the line : df1.columns = df.columns , ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 7 elements

Comment: Awesome. that works. Thanks a lot for taking your time out for this. :) learned a nice logic today. Thanks again

Comment: @anky_91 - You are welcome! And thank you for support ;)